# Add a button after a loop has iterated a specific number of times

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, rendering, modulo

I have created 3 variables:

```
let first_product = 0;
let second_product = 20;
let page_number = 1;
```

I have then looped through an Array:

```
for (let i of myArray) {
    // Perform actions
}
```

Once the for loop has looped through 20 items, I want to display the next 20 items onto a new page. I have done this using the following code:

```
let paginated_products = products.slice(first_product, second_product);

for (let i of myArray) {
    // Perform Actions

    if (i === second_product) {
        let button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = page_number;
        page_number += 1;
        document.getElementById('nav-buttons').appendChild(button);
        first_product += 20;
        second_product += 20;
    }
}
```

However, the buttons are not displayed.

If I remove the if condition, a new button is created each time a loop iteration is run.

How could I cause a buttons to be shown only when the loop is running the iteration of the value second_product (when the loop is at iteration 20, 40, 60 etc).

Comment: I posted an answer but there is some confusion on the exact goal you are trying to achieve. IT's not clear why you slice the array and then you loop through `myArray` that's not defined anywhere. But more importantly you talk about `next page` ... but you didn't make clear the whole game. So I could only address the `page` part saying something incomplete.

Comment: Can you be more clear? because to strictly answer the question _"How could I cause a buttons to be shown only when the loop is running the iteration of the value second_product (when the loop is at iteration 20, 40, 60 etc).?"_ it's simply `if(i % 20 == 0)` that will be true every time i is divisible by 20 (0, 20, 40, 60...)

Comment: The ```if (i % 20 == 0)``` is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of `products` and you need to determine to which page belongs the current product you are iterating, you need to just do the math:

```
const pageNumber = Math.floor(iProduct / productsPerPage)+1;
```

And to determine when the page turns to the next, still while iterating, you can still do the math using the modulo operator:

```
if(iProduct % productsPerPage == 0){
```

Here in this demo I show how to iterate over the `products` array and render the buttons for the correspondent page:

```js
//builds the products array with 100 objects
const products =
  ((n)=>{
    const a = [];
    for(let i=1;i<=n;i++){ a.push({cod:i}); }
    return a;
  })(100);

processProducts(products, 20);

/**
 * Loops through all the passed products and renders the buttons for each page
 */
function processProducts(products, productsPerPage){
  //for each single product in products
  iProduct = 0;
  for (let product of products) {  
  
    //[perform Actions on the current product]
  
    //here I determine which page the current product belongs to  
    const pageNumber = Math.floor(iProduct / productsPerPage)+1;  

    //if the current product is the first of its page
    if(iProduct % productsPerPage == 0){
      //render a button for the correspondent page
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerHTML = pageNumber;
      document.getElementById('nav-buttons').appendChild(button);         
    }      

    //increment the product index
    iProduct++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-buttons"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach was to write a function which does create an array of array-chunks from any provided array and provided chunk size. Creating chunks is based on the [modulo/remainder (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) and e.g a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task.

The following steps then would be ...

- Creating an array of product batches from the `products` array by passing it to the chunks creating function.
- Iterating the array of product batches via e.g. [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) where the [`index` parameter of the callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax) equals the page number value less 1 (hence `index` is zero based).

  While iterating the product batches one ...

  - should take care of the rendering of the pagination buttons.
  - could take care of each product item of the currently processed batch.

```js
function chunkArray(arr, chunkCount) {
  return arr.reduce((list, item, idx) => {
    if (idx % chunkCount === 0) {

      list.push([ item ]);
    } else {
      // list.at(-1).push(item);
      list[list.length - 1].push(item);
    }
    return list;
  }, []);
}

const products = Array
  .from({ length: 14 }, (_, idx) => `product_${ idx + 1 }`);

const productBatches = chunkArray(products, 5);

console.log({
  products,
  productBatches,
});

function createPaginationButton(pageNumber) {
  let elm = document.createElement('button');
  elm.textContent = pageNumber;
  document.querySelector('#nav-buttons').appendChild(elm);
}
productBatches
  // - process each product batch.
  .forEach((batch, batchIndex) => {

    // - for example create a paginated
    //   list of products per batch.

    batch.forEach((product, productIndex) => {
      // - do whatever needs to be done
      //   with/to each product item.
    });

    createPaginationButton(batchIndex + 1);
  });
```

```html
<div id="nav-buttons"></div>
```